# HTMLText in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have an UITextView which takes data from XML. Now that XML node is basically a html node viz.

```
"font face='Monaco' size='3'>Hello<b><i><font color=#EE0000>World</font></i></b>123</font".
```

I have following code :

```
myTextView.text = value of the xml ("font face='Monaco' size='3'>Hello<b><i><font color=#EE0000>World</font></i></b>123</font").
```

How to convert this into html so that the UITextView translate the node into html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use UIWebView and its loadHTMLString method:

```
-(void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html